How to add more space between the concatenate of two columns in sql query
In Apex select list i have columns concatenate with 2 values like ,
My query is
SELECT DISTINCT (COUNTRY_DESC || ' ' || COUNTRY_ID) d , COUNTRY_ID r FROM
FROM ADDRESS ;
Output is :
India IN
United kingdom UK
United states US

But her i want output as below, the output should align with space as shown below , how to achieve this
Expected Output:
India             IN
United kingdom    UK
United states     US

How to achieve this?

The cheapest would be to have a COUNTRY_DESC CHAR instead of VARCHAR.

Haha, @Joop, that's a good idea (kind of), but it doesn't have any effect in Apex' select list items (apart from the fact that keeping data in CHAR columns isn't really a good idea).

@Littlefoot I was afraid of that. I refrain from using CHAR too. Here it would have fitted for once.

Unfortunately, simple options others already suggested (keeping data in a CHAR datatype column or RPAD) don't work in Apex.

Here's one option which actually works.
Sample table:
create table test (id           varchar2(2),
                   country_desc varchar2(80)
                  );
insert into test values ('India', 'IN');
insert into test values ('United Kingdom', 'UK');

In Apex, create a select list item (e.g. P4_COUNTRY) whose LoV query does use RPAD function, but with Unicode non-breaking space characters:
select rpad(country_desc, 30, unistr('\00a0\00a0\00a0')) || id as d, 
       id as r
from test

Additionally, set Inline CSS page property to
#P4_COUNTRY{
  font-family: monospace;
}

Without it, description and ID would contain designed number of spaces in between, but output would still look ugly.
Run the page; result is as follows:


Interesting, this doesn't work form me. The selected value is properly formatted with monospace, but the select list itself shows variable width. Tried in chrome/edge and firefox....

This is Apex 23.2.3 on Firefox, @Koen. Tried it on Chrome, works as well. Hm, strange ...

Great this is working as expected, but when i use the below font its not aligned properly any specific reason
#P4_COUNTRY{
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}

This solution only works for fixed-width (monospace) fonts, every character needs to have same width. Helvetica is a proportional font (all glyphs do not have the same width)
